# How to use this CSS rule for divs? [JSFiddle]

Tags: css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/ZNS49/

I'd like the mainBody div to take up what space he has on the right. Also, the text shouldn't leave the mainBody div.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do appear to be on the right track, although you do not need to set the width for `#mainBody` to a fixed amount.  If you change the width setting for a fixed `200px` to `100%`, your mainbody div will take up whatever room to the right it has available.

Comment: But when I set the width to 100%, it goes under the other two divs and fills up the container div. I want it to stay on the same place as the other two divs and stretch to the right.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood what you wanted.  See this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Khzhb/  Changing all of the inner divs to use percentage widths instead of fixed widths allows them to grow to the full space available.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fork.  Not entirely sure if it is what you want based on your question (it is a tad vague) but hopefully this is close:

http://jsfiddle.net/PxNjm/